# Getting the (Stata) margins from fractional regression (=glm with family quasibinomial) for an ordinal variable in R

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, stata, marginal-effect, quasi-likelihood

I first found this really nice [Stata video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lLCGFjT0C18) on fractional regression (the dependent variable is a proportion including 0 and 1). I am especially interested in how he applies the margin approach to measure the effect of a dummy variable (2:32 - 2:58).

I also found this really nice [blog](https://m-clark.github.io/posts/2019-08-20-fractional-regression/) on fractional regression, and its counterparts in `R`, which shows that fractional regression is simply a `glm` with family `quasibinomial`. So far, so great!

Now the only thing that this blog does not explain, is how to apply the `margins` function from Stata, to the `R` approaches listed. I am especially interested in the `quasibinomial`.

I found [this margins package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/margins/vignettes/Introduction.html) for `R`, but it does not really mention either dummies, factors, ordinal or categorical variables. If someone could show me how to utilise this package, to get the marginal effect of a dummy/ordinal variable that would be amazing.

Comment: What exactly do you want to find out using marginal effects? The `emmeans` package is popular and quite comprehensive to calculate and compare marginal effects. But without more specific information, it's difficult to say more.

Comment: @COOLSerdash Thank you for your comment. I am not super sure how to make it clearer than the video fragment. Essentially, I am just looking for a clear way to explain the interpretation of a dummy variable or ordinal variable in a `glm` regression. I am going through the `margins` package at the moment, and I think maybe it can be achieved by evaluating the dummy at 1 and 0 with `at` and similarly for an ordinal variable. Maybe I was a little bit too quick with posting this question. But if I figure it out, I will add an answer myself. If I cannot, I will check `emmeans` as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To illustrate how to calculate the marginal effect of a categorical variable, I'll use the `sprogram` data that is mentioned in the video from Stata. Here is the output from Stata including the marginal effect of `summer`:

```
fracreg logit prate i.summer pdonations freemeals

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
       prate |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
      summer |
        yes  |    .579492   .0517463    11.20   0.000     .4780711     .680913
  pdonations |   .0415092   .0108759     3.82   0.000     .0201928    .0628257
   freemeals |  -.5200508   .0912252    -5.70   0.000    -.6988489   -.3412526
       _cons |   1.203022   .0719935    16.71   0.000     1.061917    1.344126
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

margins r.summer

--------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |   Contrast   Std. Err.     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+------------------------------------------------
      summer |
(yes vs no)  |   .0930492   .0089097      .0755864    .1105119
--------------------------------------------------------------
```

Here is the replication in R:

```
library(margins)
library(sandwich)
library(lmtest)

dat <- read.csv("sprogram.csv", sep=";")
# The model
mod <- glm(prate~summer + freemeals + pdonations, data = dat, family = quasibinomial())
```

To replicate Stata's standard errors ([almost](https://ramorel.github.io/posts/se-in-r-and-stata/)), we need to use robust standard errors:

```
print(coeftest(mod, vcov = vcovHC(mod, type = "HC1")), digits = 6)

              Estimate Std. Error  z value   Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  1.2030216  0.0721018 16.68504 < 2.22e-16 ***
summeryes    0.5794920  0.0518241 11.18190 < 2.22e-16 ***
freemeals   -0.5200508  0.0913621 -5.69219 1.2542e-08 ***
pdonations   0.0415092  0.0108923  3.81089 0.00013847 ***
```

Finally, we use `margins` together with robust standard errors for the marginal effect of `summer`:

```
res <- margins(mod, variable = "summer", type = "response", vcov = vcovHC(mod, type = "HC1"))

summary(res)

    factor    AME     SE       z      p  lower  upper
 summeryes 0.0930 0.0089 10.4488 0.0000 0.0756 0.1105
```

The results are virutally identical.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time! I really appreciate it!

Comment: @Tom No problem. You've answered your question practically yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `margins` package to evaluate the effect of a dummy or ordinal variable.

## Dummy variable

```
library(haven) # foreign::read.dta does not work for some reason.
d <- read_dta("http://www.stata-press.com/data/r16/401k.dta")

# code from https://m-clark.github.io/posts/2019-08-20-fractional-regression/
model_quasi = glm(
  prate ~ mrate + ltotemp + age + sole,
  data = d,
  family = quasibinomial
)
(m <- margins(model_quasi))
summary(m)

  factor     AME     SE        z      p   lower   upper
     age  0.0044 0.0004  12.2908 0.0000  0.0037  0.0051
 ltotemp -0.0264 0.0017 -15.5742 0.0000 -0.0297 -0.0230
   mrate  0.1473 0.0086  17.0834 0.0000  0.1304  0.1642
    sole  0.0211 0.0061   3.4310 0.0006  0.0090  0.0331
```

If we now compare the coefficient of the `R` output to the coefficient of the Stata output, we see that it is almost identical:

[image]

Stata code:

```
use https://www.stata-press.com/data/r16/401k
fracreg logit prate mrate c.ltotemp c.age i.sole
margins r.sole
```

## Ordinal variable

```
d$cutage <- cut(d$age, c(0,10,20,30, 100), right=FALSE)
model_quasi = glm(
    prate ~ mrate + ltotemp + cutage + sole,
    data = d,
    family = quasibinomial
)
(m <- margins(model_quasi))
summary(m)

         factor     AME     SE        z      p   lower   upper
  cutage[10,20)  0.0582 0.0068   8.5954 0.0000  0.0449  0.0715
  cutage[20,30)  0.0922 0.0082  11.2253 0.0000  0.0761  0.1083
 cutage[30,100)  0.0861 0.0103   8.3495 0.0000  0.0659  0.1064
        ltotemp -0.0258 0.0017 -15.3155 0.0000 -0.0291 -0.0225
          mrate  0.1490 0.0086  17.2847 0.0000  0.1321  0.1658
           sole  0.0206 0.0061   3.3488 0.0008  0.0085  0.0326
```

In Stata:

```
egen cutage = cut(age), at(0,10,20,30,100)
fracreg logit prate mrate c.ltotemp i.cutage i.sole

margin r.cutage

Contrasts of predictive margins                 Number of obs     =      4,075
Model VCE    : Robust

Expression   : Conditional mean of prate, predict()

------------------------------------------------
             |         df        chi2     P>chi2
-------------+----------------------------------
      cutage |
  (10 vs 0)  |          1       85.73     0.0000
  (20 vs 0)  |          1      163.36     0.0000
  (30 vs 0)  |          1       69.09     0.0000
      Joint  |          3      226.53     0.0000
------------------------------------------------

--------------------------------------------------------------
             |            Delta-method
             |   Contrast   Std. Err.     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+------------------------------------------------
      cutage |
  (10 vs 0)  |    .058218   .0062878      .0458941    .0705418
  (20 vs 0)  |   .0922323   .0072163      .0780886     .106376
  (30 vs 0)  |   .0861435   .0103634      .0658316    .1064554
--------------------------------------------------------------
```